# C++ Binding: How to bind a c++ object to JS

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[Re-post from v8-users google discussion groups].

Hello,

I am a newbie Chrome extension developer. I am currently working on a 
new extension for which I need to know on how to bind a c++ object to 
JS.

I am trying to implement the following: 
C++ Code: 
`Class Foo { 
    public: 
     Foo(); 
     ~Foo(); 
      Baz GetBazOj(); 
    private: 
     Baz baz_; 
    };`

```
Class Baz { 
 public: 
   Baz(); 
   ~Baz(); 
   int MethodBaz(); 
 private: 
   int value_; 
  }; `
```

In Javascript, I want to create the instance of c++ class and access 
their member functions like this:

```
var fooObj1 = new Foo(); 
var fooObj2 = new Foo(); 
var baz1 = fooObj1.GetBazObj(); 
var baz2 = fooObj2.GetBazObj(); 
var baz1Value = baz1.MethodBaz(); 
var baz2Value = baz2.MethodBaz();
```

In Chromium extensions internals source code, I found some reference 
to NPAPI based CPPBoundClass. I thought NPAPI functions is for Plugin. 
I am not sure on how to use this class to do the require c++ bindings. 
Can someone provide some examples and some information regarding this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use C++ in an extension, only in a plugin, so if you want to have an extension that makes use of C++ code you have to package your C++ code as a plugin and then bundle that plugin with your extension.

There's no difference between an NPAPI plugin that's for general use and one that's bundled in a plugin except for the way users install it. So you'd need to read up on how to do NPAPI/JS communication to make your plugin, and then read the Chromium extension documentation on packaging and using an NPAPI plugin.

Comment: Whenever an extension api is called, I want to perform some actions (such as DB/IO access) in the browser process and return those objects to JS. With NPAPI plugins, I cannot add utility classes to my JS namespace. I need to instantiate the new plugin element (<object>/<embed>) and call the methods on that plugin element. Is it right?  If so, I don't want to create any new elements to the html file, just to bind with C++ code. Do I have any other option to do the C++ bindings?

Comment: I read http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#templates. But I am not sure if I am allowed to use these in chrome/renderer/extensions/*_bindings.cc files?? (I did not see any code reference to ObjectTemplate or custom FunctionTemplates or AccessorInfo objects). Sorry for asking these basic questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The V8 embedding doc has nothing to do with what you are trying to do. It's for people who have C++ applications and want to embed an instance of the V8 engine into it. Unless you are planning on making a custom build of Chromium with your code built into it, looking at V8 code and Chromium implementation details isn't going to help you. If you are building an extension you are limited by the capabilities outlined in the Chromium extension documentation.

Comment: smorgan: I should have asked my question clearly. I want to write a new extension API which can be called from extension JS. I can make a custom build of Chromium. I want to write an extension which calls this new API. The new API should return a object which has methods and data members.

Comment: smorgan:  In extension JS, I want to do the following.

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
       experimental.custom.getFooObject(function(FooObj) {
            var sum = FooObj.val1 + FooObj.val2;
            FooObj.SetSum(sum);
            var storedSumVal = FooObj.GetSum();
        });
});

In C++, I will be having a Foo Class.

Class Foo {
  public:
     void SetSum(int sum);
      int  GetSum();
      int val1;
      int val2;
      int sum;
};
I am trying to bind this JS object to a native C++ class. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "I want to make a custom build of Chromium with a new extensions API" and "I want to write an extension" are wildly different questions. You should either update your actual question or post a new question if you want to increase the chance of someone answering it. Just explaining deep in a comment thread on one answer isn't likely to be noticed by anyone.

Comment: smorgan: I agree. Thanks a lot for all your replies.